# WP_Query multiple post results

Tags: php, wp-query, loop, woocommerce-offtopic

I am using WooCommerce with Wordpress. I am trying to return all the items within a category, however, I am returning multiple results depending on how many items I have.

When I only had two t-shirt pictures, it would display each picture twice. Once I added a third shirt, it would show each shirt 3 times. My code is:

```
        $args = array( 
            'post_type' => 'product', 
            'stock' => 1, 
            'posts_per_page' => 9,
            'product_cat' => $pagename, 
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            foreach ( $loop->posts as $p ) {
                $products = new WC_Product($p->ID);

                echo "<div class='col-md-4'>";
                the_post_thumbnail();
                echo "</div>";

                wp_reset_query();    
            }
        endwhile; 
    ?>
```

I have tried moving the `wp_reset_query()` to multiple places (ie within the foreach loop) however the best I get is one div with the proper photo and then a number of blank divs. When using `var_dump()`, it looks like it may be the new `WP_Query($args)` itself.

I was previously using `wp_reset_postdata()` and have switched to `wp_reset_query()` due to some of the results found on here, but it has not helped.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is wrong, you should not use to foreach inside the while, simply add the classic the_post () using the variable of your loop in this case $ loop

for example

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => 'product', 
        'stock' => 1, 
        'posts_per_page' => 9,
        'product_cat' => $pagename, 
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while($loop->have_posts()){
        $loop->the_post();
        ?>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
?>
```